# Looking for a 1980s movie I watched as a child about people being burned

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

All I can remember is humans being burned on a laboratory table, in the dark. They were rocking side to side, screaming in pain. Their entire outsides becoming dark, and their skin wrinkling. There were strands that were on their heads and bodies.

When the guy rescued the woman they ran and got into a car. To get out, they had to run these things over. They didn't look like they had a torso anymore. Sticks for hands. Constant screeching. Perhaps it might've been a short in the show called *The Dark Side*? I think they lured than trapped her in the room. They were out in the middle of nowhere. Looked like an old house. She came looking for the guy. I think something was talking to her/them. Right before they were gonna be either trapped &/or the place was gonna explode? He may have cut the wire before that happened.

I been searching on and off over the years. I was about 8-9 years old at the time. I watched it on TV in 1988-89. I've ruled out *Night of the Living Dead* and *Human Experiments*.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE. You said "_when the guy rescued the woman they ran_"; what guy and what woman? Could you [edit] in anything you remember about them perhaps?  Why is the man recusing the woman? Where is the woman? Was she captured or kidnapped or grown out of a test-tube?